# How to submit a form that has data for 2 models on Spring and let it validate them?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Suppose I have 2 tables: users and preferences.

users table has columns username, password and email.

preferences table has columns contact_me_by_email, contact_me_by_phone_call, contact_me_by_sms.

Each table has it's own model (User and Preferences).

I want to present just one page for users so that when they fill in data in the form that data will be validated and will populate both tables.

I'm able to get all parameters from one form by accessing the Request object and manually performing all validations and proceed according to the results I get.

Also, I can successfully use @Validate annotation to validate models when I present 2 pages for user (each page having just one model - first page contains only data for User model and the second one contains only data for preferences).

I'm struggling to discover a way to present one page only with a form that contains all fields from both models above that could be validated by Spring using the @Validate annotation.

Is that possible? Is there any other annotation I'm not aware of that could do it?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: How about annotating the fields in preferences as transient in User. Then you need just one submit button. At the service layer, you can process that form and separate the user information from preferences information and pass it along to their respective DAO's. I would do a one-to-one association between user and users preference. I hope this is your doubt.

Comment: That's a great solution for me. If you put your suggestion as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Regards.

Comment: Done. I hope the pseudo code is enough.. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is your user mode class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User(){

// Fields of your user annotated with @Column

and fields of your preferences annotated @Transient as below :

@Transient
private String favoriteTvShow;
//getters and setters for both
}
```

This way you need to submit only one form. Enjoy.